# Which library to link (OSX)

Tags: c, macos, build, linker

Can someone put me right please. I'm linking using `-lIOKit` but clearly need another library too.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___CFConstantStringClassReference", referenced from:
      CFString in code-9daAw9.o
  "_kCFBooleanTrue", referenced from:
      _dimDisplayNow in code-9daAw9.o
```

Here is the code (found at http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/191807-sleep-display.html)

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <IOKit/IOKitLib.h>

static int dimDisplayNow(void) 
{
    io_registry_entry_t r =
        IORegistryEntryFromPath(kIOMasterPortDefault,
        "IOService:/IOResources/IODisplayWrangler");
    if(!r) return 1;
    int err = IORegistryEntrySetCFProperty(r, CFSTR("IORequestIdle"),
                                           kCFBooleanTrue);
    IOObjectRelease(r);
    return err;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    dimDisplayNow();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" that could mean that you only have the 32-bit version of the library. If building with `-m32` works, that would be it.

Comment: No, same error but changes to i386 from x86_64

Comment: Ah, well, was worth a try. I'm sorry, but I can't help you here, no idea about cocoa (that's Mac, isn't it?).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to link against the [CoreFoundation.framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CoreFoundation_Collection/_index.html), which is what you've included on the first line of code. (The `CF` in `___CFConstantStringClassReference` and `kCFBooleanTrue` stand for CoreFoundation).

Comment: Yes, I had assumed that too, but I get `ld: library not found for -lCoreFoundation` and truly there is nothing that looks likely in `/usr/lib` (where `IOKit` is).  What is the library called / where is it?

Comment: Use `-framework CoreFoundation` instead of `-l`. (It's in `/System/Library/Frameworks`, but you shouldn't worry too much about that.)

Comment: Thanks. Sadly the program doesn't work for me but it does now compile :-)